# How to parse current data to scenario in cucumber feature file

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java

I want to parse a current date to step that is editing given field in request file.

Example:
Request

{
id: "string",
date: "string" (must be today)
}

So I have step to insert given string in feature file, but I dont know how can I parse current date

Thank you for any help

Comment: Please elaborate your question and provide more details.

Comment: IMHO some kind of wildcard (`--TODAY--`) which will be replaced in the step definition (when present) is quite ok

Comment: Are you asking how to produce a json file with the current date in java?